# c++での分割コンパイル

Tags: c++, preprocessor

test2.hに宣言されている名前空間Bでtest1.hに宣言されている名前空間Aに宣言されたクラスをメンバとしているのですが, 以下のようなエラーが出ます.

test1.hでの `#include"test2.h"` を消せば上手く行くのは分かったのですが, なぜ上手く行くのかが分からないです. よろしくお願いします.

**エラーメッセージ**

```
    test2.h test1.h
In file included from test1.h:3:0,
                 from test1.cpp:1,
                 from test3.cpp:2:
test2.h:7:5: error: ‘A’ does not name a type
     A::K t;
     ^
In file included from test3.cpp:3:0:
test2.cpp: In function ‘void B::Func()’:
test2.cpp:3:2: error: ‘t’ was not declared in this scope
  t.k=100;
  ^
test2.cpp:3:2: note: suggested alternative: ‘tm’
  t.k=100;
  ^
  tm
In file included from test1.h:3:0:
test2.h:7:5: error: ‘A’ does not name a type
     A::K t;
```

#### ソースコード

test1.h

```
#ifndef test1_H_
#define test1_H_
#include<iostream>
#include"test2.h"
namespace A{
 class K{
  public:
  int k;
  void main();
 };
};
#endif
```

test1.cpp

```
#include"test1.h"
void A::K::main(){
 std::cout << A::K::k << std::endl;
}
```

test2.h

```
#ifndef test2_H_
#define test2_H_
#include<iostream>
#include"test1.h"
namespace B{
 A::K t;
 void Func();
};
#endif
```

test2.cpp

```
#include"test2.h"
void B::Func(){
 t.k=100;
 t.main();
}
```

test3.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"test1.cpp"
#include"test1.h"
#include"test2.cpp"
#include"test2.h"
int main(){
 B::Func();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

うまく行かない理由は、先に回答されている方の書かれた通りなのですが、では、どう書くのが正しいのか、について書いてみたいと思います。

ヘッダファイル test1.h と test2.h のように複数のヘッダファイルを作っていく場合には、依存関係が単一方向になるように設計する必要があります。

test1.h の先頭で test2.h をincludeするのであれば、test2.hの方ではtest1.hをincludeしてはいけません。逆もしかりです。

今回のヘッダファイルの内容を見ると、test2.hの記載内容をコンパイラが理解するためにはtest1.hの内容が必要ですが、test1.hをコンパイルするためにはtest2.hの内容をコンパイラが先に見ておく必要はありません。

ですので、test2.hからtest1.hをインクルードするようにします。

次にソースファイルですが、ソースファイルからソースファイルをインクルードすることはしません。

この例題ではソースファイルがtest1.cppと test2.cppとtest3.cppの3つしか登場しませんが、実際のプロジェクトではソースファイルが何千とか何万というのはざらです。そのような状況では１つ１つのソースファイルを別々にコンパイルします。
そのようにして何がうれしいかというと、一部のソースに加筆や修正を行ったときに、修正した一部のソースファイルだけコンパイルすることが可能になります。

今回のtest3.cppのように中心となる１つのソースファイルから、残りのソースファイルを全部includeしてしまっては、分割した意味がなくなってしまいます。

ですので、test3.cppから他のソースをincludeするのはやめて、test1.cpp、test2.cpp、test3.cppはそれぞれ独立にコンパイルして、最後にリンクします。

コンパイル操作はたとえば次のようにします。

```
$ g++ -c test1.cpp
$ g++ -c test2.cpp
$ g++ -c test3.cpp
$ g++ -o test123 test1.o test2.o test3.o
```

こんなのを毎回手で打っていてはたまらないのでツールで自動化します。

test1.cppのソースファイルをコンパイルするのに必要なヘッダは test1.h だけですので、test1.cppからは test1.h だけをincludeします。必要ないものまでincludeするとコンパイル時間がそれだけ余計にかかります。

test2.cpp, test3.cpp についても同様です。

ヘッダもソースも、必要最小限のヘッダファイルをincludeするように設計します。

## 追記

ときには、２つのヘッダに、お互いをincludeさせたくなることがあります。

典型的には、２つの構造体(struct)またはクラスが、互いを参照しているようなケースです。

たとえば、グラフ構造を表現するプログラムを書いているときに、節点(Node)と枝（Edge)のクラスがあって、Nodeの定義の中にEdgeを登場させたい、一方でEdgeの定義の中でNodeを登場させたい、ということがあったとしましょう。

コンパイラはファイルを先頭から最後まで順に処理するので、NodeとEdgeのどちらを定義するのか、決めないといけません。Nodeを先に書いたとしましょう。

そうしたら、Nodeの中でEdgeを参照したいときには、Edgeの定義をまだ読み込んでいません。

このような場合に使える技として、「定義」ではなく「宣言」を先に済ませる、というのがあります。

次のように書きます。

```
class Node; // Nodeの宣言。定義は後ほど登場する。
            // 宣言により、"Node"がコンパイラに型名として認知される。

class Edge { // Edge の定義。Edgeの内容を記述する。
public:
   // Node の宣言しか、コンパイラは見ていない。
   // この状況でも可能な操作は、Nodeのポインタ型の変数の定義。
   // どの型のポインタも同じサイズなので、何かのポインタ、という情報だけで、
   // コンパイラは記憶領域のサイズを決定したり、コピー処理の命令を作り出せる
   // それ以上のことは、何もできない。
   Node *getSourceNode();
   Node *getDestinationNode();
   void setSourceNode(Node *n);
   void setDestinationNode(Node *n);
private:
   Node *source_node_;
   Node *destination_node_;
   // ファイルを下まで読むと Node には inward_edge_count_ なるメンバが
   // 定義されていることがわかるが、この行を処理している時点ではコンパイラは
　 // それを見ていないので、たとえば source_node_->inward_edge_count_ = 0;
   // などと、ここに書くと、コンパイルエラーになる。
};

// あとから、Nodeを定義する

class Node {
public:
  int getOutwardEdgeCount();
  Edge *getOutwardEdge(int edge_index);
  void addOutwardEdge(Edge *e);
  int getInwardEdgeCount();
  Edge *getInwardEdge(int edge_index);
  void addInwardEdge(Edge *e);
private:
  // このNodeから出ていくedge
  int outward_edge_count_;
  Edge *outward_edges_[10]; // 最大10個まで記憶できる
  // このNodeに入ってくるedge
  int inward_edge_count_;
  Edge *inward_edges_[10];
};
```

このような書き方をすれば、相互に参照しあう型を定義できます。
上記の２つのクラス NodeとEdgeは、互いに密接に関係していて、つねにセットで
使われるでしょうから、典型的には１つのヘッダファイルに、２つのクラスを書きます。

NodeとEdgeを別々のヘッダファイルに分けて書くことも可能です。その場合には次のようにします。

- Edge.h の中には Nodeの宣言とEdgeの定義を入れます。
- Node.h の中には Edge.hのinclude指令と、Nodeの定義を入れます。

ファイル間の参照関係はあくまでも一方通行であり、どちらにどちらを参照させるのかは、設計者がしっかり決める必要があります。

C/C++はそういう言語です。

これがたとえばjavaだと相互に参照してもOKですね。コンパイラがファイルを読む読み方が、C/C++とはだいぶ違うので。

Comment: もしtest1.hの記載内容をコンパイラが理解するためにtest2.hの内容が必要だった場合はどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: それはたぶん設計が悪いです（相互に依存しあう＝密結合）どうしても相互依存する必要があることは、ないわけではないのですが、そういう場合は「宣言」（定義にならない宣言）を先行させるとよいことが多いです。

Comment: ２つのヘッダファイルの内容が相互に参照している場合の書き方について追記しました。

Comment: NodeとEdgeを別々のヘッダファイルに分けて書く場合に,これらのクラスを呼び出したいときにはNode.hをincludeするだけで大丈夫ですか？

Comment: 示したソース例では、Node.hからEdge.hをincludeしてるので、芋づる式にEdgeクラスの定義も読み込まれることになるので、大丈夫です。

Answer (score 7):

`test3.cpp`の`#include`の内容を忠実に追えばわかることです。

```
#include<iostream>   // これは質問と関係ないので追わない
#include"test1.cpp"
  #include"test1.h"
    #ifndef test1_H_
    #define test1_H_       // test1_H_がここで定義される
    #include<iostream>     // これは質問と関係ないので追わない
    #include"test2.h"
      #ifndef test2_H_
      #define test2_H_
      #include<iostream>   // これは質問と関係ないので追わない
      #include"test1.h"
        #ifndef test1_H_   // test1_H_は定義済みなので#endifまで無視される
        #endif
      namespace B{
       A::K t;             // ここより上にAに関する宣言が存在しない
       void Func();
      };
      #endif
    namespace A{
     class K{
      public:
      int k;
      void main();
     };
    };
    #endif
  void A::K::main(){
    std::cout << A::K::k << std::endl;
  }
#include"test1.h"
#include"test2.cpp"
#include"test2.h"
int main(){
 B::Func();
}
```

見て明らかなように、 `A::K t;` に到達した時点で、 `A` に関する宣言・定義いずれもありません。ですのでエラーになります。

---

というように、`#include`はいい感じに解決してくれる魔法のキーワードというわけではなく、愚直に指定された行に指定されたファイルの内容をインクルードする機能です。
逆に言えば、`#include`結果は開発者にも正確に理解できる機能であり、test3.cppで書かれた

```
#include"test1.cpp"
#include"test1.h"
#include"test2.cpp"
#include"test2.h"`
```

のように何でもかんでも`#include`すれば問題が解決できるなどと考えるべきではありません。もっとご自身の書いたソースコードに目を向けましょう。